# scale image in Drupal

Tags: 7, media

I need to scale image in Drupal 7.
IF the width is greater than the height, THEN scale the image to 200px height.
IF the height is greater than the width, THEN scale the image to 200px width.
and if the width and height are the same, scale to 200x200.
Please help me out.

Comment: height is you preference or width or you would like exactly 200x200 ?

Comment: At-least 200x200. If width is greater then height then need to scale width, same vice-versa for height.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this module will do the trick:

[ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions)

> **Effects provided**
>
> ...
>
> - Aspect Switcher - lets you perform different actions or use different    dimensions based on whether the image is 'landscape' or
>     'portrait'

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image style  Configuration » Media » Image styles. Add new image style and add scale property to it. Apply that image style to image field.